# Can't send e-mail on submit?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a web site. In this web site I have a contacts page which has name,e-mail, phone and question input texts. It supposed to check for required fields and if they are filled, user can submit an e-mail. It neither checks required fields nor sends e-mail. Just postbacks to the home page. How can I fix this?

Here is the sample init.js for contacts page submit:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  "use strict";
  $("#contactForm .error").remove();
  var e = $("#contactForm");
  var t = $("#contactForm_submit");
  var n = $(".successMsg");
  e.on("submit", function(r) {
    var i = false;
    $(".required").each(function() {
      if(jQuery.trim($(this).val()) === "") {
        $(this).parent().append('<span class="error"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i></span>');
        i = true
      } else if($(this).hasClass("email")) {
        var e = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w]+\.)+[\w]{2,4})?$/;
        if(!e.test(jQuery.trim($(this).val()))) {
          $(this).parent().append('<span class="error"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i></span>');
          i = true
        }
      }
    });
    if(!i) {
      r.preventDefault();
      $.ajax({
        url: "js/inc/sendemail.php",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "html",
        data: e.serialize(),
        beforeSend: function() {
          n.fadeOut();
          t.html("Sending....")
        },
        success: function(t) {
          e.fadeOut(300);
          n.html(t).fadeIn(1e3);
          setTimeout(function() {
            n.html(t).fadeOut(300);
            $("#formName, #formEmail,#phone, #message").val("");
            e.fadeIn(1800)
          }, 4e3)
        },
        error: function(e) {
          console.log(e)
        }
      });
      $(".required").val("")
    }
    return false
  });
  $("#contactForm input").focus(function() {
    $("#contactForm .error").remove()
  });
  $("#contactForm textarea").focus(function() {
    $("#contactForm .error").remove()
  })
})
```

The demo site is [www.ioterm.com](http://www.ioterm.com/) You can navigate to contacts via the bottom link.

edit 1: As I said, I removed all angularjs and replaced it with jquery-lang.js. (https://github.com/irrelon/jquery-lang-js ) But still I can not send mail even it is not checking required fields!

edit2: Here is the php file:

```
<?php

$name = $_REQUEST['name'];
$email = $_REQUEST['email'];
$message = $_REQUEST['message'];
$name = strtolower($name);
$name = ucwords($name);

$to = 'test@gmail.com';
$subject = 'Website message from: '.$name;
$message = 'FROM: '.$name." \nEmail: ".$email."\nMessage: \n".$message;


$send = mail($to, $subject, $message);

?>
```

Best Regards.

Comment: Why use angular if you're just going to write the whole thing with JQuery?

Comment: @lux couldn't find how to quickly add multiple language support

Comment: may be I can use https://github.com/Irrelon/jquery-lang-js in order not to use angularjs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your page is giving an error

```
"Uncaught TypeError: $(...).kenburnsy is not a function"
```

I think you are missing a reference for that plugin, and that corrupts your init.js for mailing function.

Comment: Google Chrome > F12 > Console

Comment: you are right thank u.  In my demo web site I got this page as a base. (http://statfa.net/twist/star-particle/) And in the contacts page of this site have the same e-mail form. When I enter an e-mail address without "@"  and submit the form, it gives an error message warning to enter "@". I wonder where does this warning message comes from? I got this message in Turkish, is it due to my local settings? Can I change this warning message language according to language selection in my sample demo web site?

Comment: It is browsers default validation error message and it is auto translated to your browsers language. Browsers auto validate inputs according to its type, like "email". If you want to disable this, you can change the type of this input to "text".

Comment: thanks for your info. One last thing, the original page [link](http://statfa.net/twist/star-particle/) has some rocket animation and a text (Email Sent Successfully) after completing the form and submit it. But I couldn't manage this in my demo page. [link](https://www.ioterm.com) What is missing on my page?

Comment: That pages sendemail.php returns the html, "<div class="content-message"><i class="fa fa-rocket"></i> Email Sent Successfully</div>". Your sendemail.php returns nothing.

Comment: Is it OK to write something like this? ` if($success)
      {
      return <div class="content-message"><i class="fa fa-rocket"></i> Email Sent Successfully</div>
      }`

Comment: I don't know php syntax much but it should be something like that

Comment: ` if($success) { return '<div class="content-message"><i class="fa fa-rocket"></i> Email Sent Successfully</div>' }` didn't work but didn't give error either.

Comment: echo '<div class="content-message"><i class="fa fa-rocket"></i> Email Sent Successfully</div>'; did the trick, thanks lot :)